# Apply pattern to column chart in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I want to apply arrow patterns to my chart, which involves a combination of stacked columns and column range types. I have experimented with various configurations but have been unable to achieve the exact appearance depicted in the image. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, in Highcharts it is not possible to set columns to end with an arrow using basic API settings. You would have to [modify the core code](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) responsible for drawing the column.

However, arrows in the middle of columns can be obtained using SVG pattern fills. However, you must have a rigid chart width set because these patterns are relative to the entire chart, not a point, so they will move when you change the width:

```js
color: {
  pattern: {
    color: 'blue',
    path: {
      d: 'M 0 0 L 25 10 M 25 10 L 50 0',
      strokeWidth: 1
    },
    width: 50,
    height: 10,
    x: 6
  }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/no6vw7cr/